# Segmentation fault in class

Tags: c++, linux, cygwin

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
class Bucket{

    public:
        Bucket();
        void setN(int n);
        void setArrayb();
        void storeArray(int s, int cc, int **A);
        int showdata(int cc);
    private:
        int n_elements;
        int *b;

    };
    Bucket :: Bucket(){

        ;
    }
    void Bucket :: setN(int n)
        {
            n_elements = n;
        }

    void Bucket :: setArrayb(){

        int *b = new int [n_elements + 1];     
      }

    void Bucket :: storeArray(int s, int cc, int **A){


         cout << this -> n_elements;
        if(cc <= n_elements){
            this -> b[cc] = A[0][s];
        }

    }

    int Bucket :: showdata(int cc){
        return this -> b[cc];
    }

int main(){

    int n = 10;
    int** A = new int*[1];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++){
        A[i] = new int [n + 1];
    }

    Bucket B[n + 1];
    A[0][3] = 6;

    int fb = 10;
    B[1].setN(fb) ;
    B[1].setArrayb();
    B[1].storeArray(3, 1, A);
    cout << B[1].showdata(1);
}
```

I'm trying to complete bucketsort with n bucket for A. n_element is the numbers of each bucket, after compiling, it's legal. But when I execute it, it cause segmentation fault.Can someone explain what happened in this code?

Using in linux environment by cygwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by your misunderstanding of what the following line does in `setArrayb`.

```
int *b = new int [n_elements + 1];
```

1. It initializes a function local variable `b`.
2. It does not do anything to the member variable of the same name.
3. It leaks memory.

When you access the elements of the member variable `b` in `storeArray`, you access an uninitialized pointer, which causes undefined behavior.

Change that line to

```
b = new int [n_elements + 1];
```

---

Unless there is a need for you to manage dynamically allocated memory in your code, change your class to use `std::vector<int>`.

If you must manage your own memory, please follow [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Answer (score 1):

in this section

```
 void Bucket :: setArrayb(){

    int *b = new int [n_elements + 1];     
  }
```

you should write `b = new int [n_elements + 1];`

Answer (score 0):

```
void Bucket :: setArrayb(){
    int *b = new int [n_elements + 1];     
}
```

It allocates memory and stores pointer to it into local variable `b`, not `this->b`.